# Mail command to send attachements

Tags: aix, sendmail, mail-command

I tried the below command

```
uuencode data.txt | mailx –s “Test Mail” “mrp@xyz.com”
```

But I get the below error

```
ksh: uuencode: not found.
Null Message body;  hope that' ok
```

which clearly tell that uuencode utility is not found.

I there any other way to send attachments with mail through command line. At the same time I don't have admin access for the same to install the utility (**I use AIX 5. version Server**)

Comment: which version of mailx do you have?  Sometimes there is a `-a` option for attachments.

Answer (score 2):

mailx can not send attachments and you don't have uuencode. If you have mime-construct, then it is relatively easy:

```
 mime-construct --output \
                --to "bernhard@localhost" \
                --file-attach fish.zip \
                --string here_you_are
```

the output:

```
To: bernhard@localhost
MIME-Version: 1.0 (mime-construct 1.9)
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=congratulations

--congratulations
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=fish.zip
Content-Type: application/zip; name=fish.zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

UEsDBBQAAgAIADKluEK3tLL0XAAAAG8AAAAEABUAZmlzaFVUCQADYLSfUSKiAVNVeAQAAAAAAC2K
wQ2AIBAE/1axDSB8tBMLIHDoJXIQOSV2ryb+JjPDHZEu9N2LA4vSkXwg+BiRuG0OeldCLsJaDqTd
rw1ShAYNNZ65wvA/moZ5cu6FVy4wHbCaq/0qyzp+9/AAUEsBAhcDFAACAAgAMqW4Qre0svRcAAAA
bwAAAAQADQAAAAAAAQAAAKSBAAAAAGZpc2hVVAUAA2C0n1FVeAAAUEsFBgAAAAABAAEAPwAAAJMA
AAAAAA==

--congratulations
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

aGVyZV95b3VfYXJl

--congratulations--
```

together with mailx:

```
mime-construct --your-options | mailx -s your_subject youruser@domain
```

Comment: @user55518 there is a typo I cannot edit (as the edition is less than 6 characters) :s/mime-contruct/mime-construct

Answer (score -1):

Try with the following

```
uuencode <old-filename> <New filename> |mailx -s <filename> mailid
```

Comment: "ksh: uuencode: not found" and "I don't have admin access for the same to install the utility"